# Microphone does not work when speaker is on

Tags: xiaomi, microphone, mute, video-calling, loudspeaker

So, for a few days I have been having problems with my microphone on video call or call with loudspeakers. I tried Whatsapp video call, Whatsapp voice call with loudspeaker, Zoom, and Google Meet and the problems are same: my voice cannot go through, while I can hear other people's voice.
I tried using mic checker app and both my microphones are fine. I also have tried recording video and audio and they both work just fine.
I also have checked the applications' permission and they do have permission to use my microphone.

Last time, I tried zoom meeting, and muted my **speaker**, and my voice went through. However, when I turn on my speaker again, my mic cannot pick up any sound.

Is there a way I can fix this so that my speaker and my mic can be on at the same time?

Comment: Does this happen in safe mode too? If yes, could be hardware issue, if no, some app is creating this mess

Comment: what do you mean by safe mode? how do I enable safe mode?

Comment: Safe mode is a mode in which the device works as if there are no installed apps. One usually needs a key combination to enter into safe mode. You didn't mention your device in question, anyway Google for *how to enter into safe mode <insert device name >*

Comment: okay, I tried it in safe mode and this happens too. So this could be a hardware issue then?

Comment: To me, it looks like a hardware issue and it's better to get it checked out by service guys